# How to output keys on different levels if value found in array

Tags: json, jq

Using jq, I would like to output multiple values on different levels of a JSON file based on whether they exist in an array.

My data looks like the following. It displays a number of hosts I examine regarding the people who have access to it:

```json
[
  {
    "server": "example_1",
    "version": "Debian8",
    "keys": [
      {
        "fingerprint": "SHA256:fingerprint1",
        "for_user": "root",
        "name": "user1"
      },
      {
        "fingerprint": "SHA256:fingerprint2",
        "for_user": "git",
        "name": "user2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "server": "example_2",
    "version": "Debian9",
    "keys": [
      {
        "fingerprint": "SHA256:fingerprint2",
        "for_user": "root",
        "name": "user2"
      },
      {
        "fingerprint": "SHA256:fingerprint2",
        "for_user": "www",
        "name": "user2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "server": "example_3",
    "version": "CentOS",
    "keys": [
      null
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to extract the value for `server` and the value of `for_user` any occurence where user2 is found as a name in `.keys[]`. Basically, the output could look like this:

```
example1, git
example2, root
example2, www
```

What I can already do is displaying the first column, so the `.server` value:

```bash
cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.keys[].name | index("user2")) | .server'`
```

How could I also print a value in the selected array element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following `jq` command:

```
jq -r '.[]|"\(.server), \(.keys[]|select(.name=="user2").for_user)"'
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Could you please describe how I could write another value like from `fingerprint` in a third column?

Comment: A bit hackish, but works :)  `jq -r '.[]|"\(.server), \(.keys[]|select(.name=="user2")|"\(.for_user), \(.fingerprint)")"'`